# How can i update hierarchy join tables

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with one situation:

I have 2 tables in mysql:

- update_streets
- verify_streets

I want to update the street on `update_streets` table by joining verify `streets` table and check whether `county` and `country` fields are the same in the both tables

```
UPDATE
update_street p
INNER JOIN
verify_streets m
ON
p.county = m.verify_streets  AND p.country = m.country AND p.street = 
m.street %%
SET
p.street = m.street
```

> Sample Data

```
verify_street
id | street        | county | country 
---|---------------|--------|--------
1  | elize glove   | varna  | bulgaria

update_street
id | street | county | country
---|--------|--------|---------
 1 | elize  | varna  | bulgaria
```

I need to update the `update_street` table with the first `street` name from `verify_street` so: elize from `update_street` become elize glove.

Answer (score 0):

From your sample data I think you need the LIKE operator:

```
UPDATE update_street p INNER JOIN verify_streets m
ON p.country = m.country  AND p.county = m.county AND m.street like concat('%', p.street, '%')
SET p.street = m.street
```

If you want the street in `verify_streets` to start and not include the street in `update_street` then change the last condition of the `ON` clause to:

```
m.street like concat(p.street, '%')
```